# Why my sizes attributes is not working? How to fix this?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```css
.responsively-lazy:not(img){
    position:relative;
    height:0;

}

.responsively-lazy:not(img) > img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  opacity:1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  

}

img.responsively-lazy{
    width:100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">


<img src="https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-1134x1536.jpg" alt="032c" class="responsively-lazy"
srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
data-srcset="https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-295x400.jpg 295w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-620x840.jpg 620w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-768x1040.jpg 768w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-1024x1387.jpg 1024w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531-1134x1536.jpg 1134w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531.jpg 1500w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531.jpg 1500w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/07/06_ich_bin_doris_tote_bag2_0003-e1602785861531.jpg 1500w"
sizes="(max-width: 800px) 20vw, 200px">
<!--PICTURE-ONE-->


<img src="https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng.jpg"
 class="responsively-lazy" srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="   data-srcset="https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-300x169.jpg 300w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-630x354.jpg 630w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-768x432.jpg 768w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-1024x576.jpg 1024w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-1536x864.jpg 1536w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng.jpg 2048w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng-1680x945.jpg 1680w, https://assets.032c.com/2020/09/toppe_cmilano_mag-eng.jpg 2048w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 1vw, 900px">

<img class="responsively-lazy"
src="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/christopher-gower-291240.jpg"
srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
data-srcset="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/christopher-gower-291240.jpg 2000w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/christopher-gower-291240-300x200.jpg 300w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/christopher-gower-291240-768x512.jpg 768w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/christopher-gower-291240-1024x682.jpg 1024w"
sizes="100vw">

<img src="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/04/Arial_view_of_Kibera-800x450.jpg"
class="responsively-lazy"
srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
data-srcset="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/04/Arial_view_of_Kibera-800x450.jpg 800w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/04/Arial_view_of_Kibera-1600x900.jpg 1600w"
sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px">

<img src="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/jaroslaw-ceborski-235039.jpg"
class="responsively-lazy"
srcset="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
data-srcset="https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/jaroslaw-ceborski-235039.jpg 2000w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/jaroslaw-ceborski-235039-300x199.jpg 300w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/jaroslaw-ceborski-235039-768x510.jpg 768w, https://staging.highrise.digital/content/uploads/2018/03/jaroslaw-ceborski-235039-1024x680.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 678px) 100vw, 678px">
```

I don't think this works on the snippet so, you can check it here: https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/LYGrxyO

The thing is that when I resize the screen, I'd spect on picture one that @ `(max-width: 800px) 20vw, 200px` but is not working.
My SIZES attribute is not changing depending on my screen size.

How to fix this?

Comment: use media query

Comment: I don't see any media queries in you snippet tho so idk how you want it to work